# Python Appium Ios Find parent element from known child element (name, not xpath)

Tags: python, ios, appium, appium-ios

I'm trying to access a parent element (of type other) that does not have label or name.
I have a type 'StaticText' element contained in type 'Other' element.
Is there a way to find the **parent** element?
(Not by using xpath)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

is there any reason why you don't want to use xpath?

Because with xpath you can do it
when you add /.. at the end of the selector